Is it important "whether concepts are defined logically or empirically" for a priori or posteriori?
I'm confused whether concepts are defined logically or empirically in order to determine if a proposition is a priori or a posteriori.

Apple is a fruit.

The sun radiates heat.

Paris is the capital of France.


Some of them say if when you once understand the concepts, you can logically go on, then it's a priori. Some of them say if the concepts are defined empirically, doesn't matter you go on yourself for the solution, it's a posteriori because it belongs to the external world.
If I learn the concepts of "apple", "the sun", "paris" from an encyclopedia, I will automatically say that all of those three propositions are a priori. Paris is (at least for now) what is the capital of France. The sun radiates heat for sure and apple is a fruit by its definition.
But still not sure because these definitions belong to observations.
Can you please help me? Thanks a lot.

A priori means independent of experience: why do you think that reading an enciclopedia is not empirical? What is empirical for you?

I think it’s empirical, but then why “all bachelors are unmarried” is a priori? Without getting the definition of “bachelor” from the external world, how do you understand this proposition is correct?

Indeed it could be said to be important and interestingly subtle or subtly interesting here in terms of with or without any external world experience for the a priori, at least per Kant when he sat in an armchair...

Your confusion stems from Kant's erroneous position that synonymity is the same as logical identity. That is, a statement is analytic if what is affirmed of the subject is synonymous with the subject. Quine did a decent job exposing why this is faulty. "A = A" is analytic in a very different manner from "all bachelors are unmarried men" is. The former is according to rules of grammar, the latter hinges on meaning or semantics.

Analytic, not a priori.
